# Fabric prompt() for passwords

Tags: python, shell, fabric

Fabric includes the [prompt()](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/api/core/operations.html) operation to collect input from the user:

```
fabric.operations.prompt(text, key=None, default='', validate=None)
```

At one point, I ask the user for a password:

```
pw = prompt('Password:')
```

When the user types his password, it's displayed in the shell in plain text. Is it possible to keep the user's input hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html

```
getpass.getpass('Password: ')
```

Comment: Correct, though `'Password: '` is already the default, so you could just do `getpass.getpass()`.